# Is there a way to print the class / function name everytime i print something in python?

Tags: python

In Python, is it possible to print the "class and function name" whenever the "Print" function is called?

For excample,

```
class SimpleClass:
    def function1(self):
        print "This is the printed msg"

c = SimpleClass()
c.function1()

"Output wanted" 
SimpleClass:function1 - "This is the printed msg"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) module instead of print statements.

The list of available attributes are located [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes), including: `args, asctime, created, exc_info, filename, funcName, levelname, levelno, lineno, module, msecs, message, msg, name, pathname, process, processName, relativeCreated, thread, threadName`.

Comment: Can you provide a small summary of what it does, along with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You're using Python 2.x it looks like, so `print` is not a function and can't be overridden like you want. You could, however, *make* `print` a function as it is in Python 3.x using `from __future__ import print_function` assuming you're using Python 2.6 or later. Then you could pretty trivially override it with your own `print` that does as you like. (Well, the overriding is trivial; getting the class and method name is a little less so.)

```
from inspect import currentframe

_print = print

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    frame = currentframe().f_back
    fname = frame.f_code.co_name
    self  = frame.f_locals.get("self", None)
    qname = (type(self).__name__ + "." + fname) if self else fname
    _print(qname, end=": ")
    _print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Digging `self` out of the function's local variables to see if it's a method is kind of a cheat, since that's only a convention and `self` could refer to any value, but it should work 99.44% of the time.

Comment: Thanks. although i've decided to use the logging module, this was the answer i was originally looking for. I learned a lot!